# Can't boot Samsung galaxy ace GT-S5830i Failed to mount /system (Invalid argument)

Tags: custom-roms, unbricking, samsung-galaxy-ace, samsung-galaxy-ace-plus

I can't boot my Samsung galaxy ace GT-S5830I after I tried to flash a custom rom built for the GT-S5830, if I try and boot into Recovery I get the following errors:

```
-- Applying Multi-CSC --
E: failed to mount /system (Invalid argument)
E: failed to mount /system (Invalid argument)
E: failed to mount /cache (Invalid argument)
E: Can't mount /cache/recovery/log
E: Can't open /cache/recovery/log
E: failed to mount /cache (Invalid argument)
E: Can't mount /cache/recovery/last_log
E: Can't open /cache/recovery/last_log
```

I have tried flashing using Odin and flashing again from the SD card using a different rom but that didn't work! Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to fix this. You have to **sideload** that ROM. For that -->

Just download adb (android debug bridge) minimum requirements. Sideload  your rom . It may seem to you that you got stuck there but don’t panic, wait at least 5 minutes. After that remove your battery and press (Power+Home+volume up) upto it shows samsung screen and then release. Then just install your rom from recovery mode.

No need to get panic on those failings. They happen sometime.